# Python pyramid_simpleform how do I deal with relationships?

Tags: python, pyramid, simple-form

I'm moving my first steps with [pyramid_simpleform](http://packages.python.org/pyramid_simpleform/) after having ever used formalchemy in Pylons 1.

The form I'm starting with is pretty simple: I have some options and user has to check one.

here the form class:

```
class OptionsSchema(Schema):
    ...
    id_opt = validators.Int(not_empty=True)
```

here it's instance in view:

```
model = DBSession.query(models.Model).first()
form = Form(request, schema=OptionsSchema, obj=model)
renderer = FormRenderer(form)
```

let's say `model.id_opt == 3`,

here I make a radio button for each `option` in `model` in template:

```
%for opt in model.options:
    ${form.radio('id_opt', value=opt.id)}
%endfor
```

what I expected to see was a `checked="checked"` for `id_opt == 3`like this:

```
<input id="id_opt_1" name="id_opt" type="radio" value="1" />    
<input id="id_opt_2" name="id_opt" type="radio" value="2" />    
<input id="id_opt_3" checked="checked" name="id_opt" type="radio" value="3" />
```

but I get none.

Must I set checked option by myself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400397/python-pyramid-how-to-use-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons